# Pass Dynamic Shortcode Value to PHP Value

Tags: php, wordpress

The purpose of this code is to retrieve test results for a particular store (user). We retrieve this data by hardcoding the Store Id like the first example below but this isn't a viable option moving forward since we have so many stores (users) setup. We now need to dynamically print the store ID of a logged in user.

Below, is an example of the $StoreId hardcoded manually and which currently works for us. However, I need to dynamically print this using the value of a shortcode.

```
 //***** Set the Store ID Here *****
$StoreId = 28;
```

The shortcode below will print the logged in users meta data I need.

```
[pcud-user-data f="surname"]
```

However, when I insert the shortcode into my PHP code, it doesn't work.

```
//***** Set the Store ID Here *****    
$StoreId = echo do_shortcode( '[pcud-user-data f="store-id"]' );
```

To confirm, the shortcode does work. If I add the shortcode into the body of my Wordpress page template using the code below, it successfully prints the users store ID onto the page. However, I don't want it to be visible on the page, it needs to be printed into the first PHP example above.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[pcud-user-data f="store-id"]' );?>
```

All the PHP code at the top of my page is below.

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Test Level
 *
 * @package Zephyr
 * @subpackage Test Results
 */

include("Functions/TestDataCalls.php");

//***** Set the Store ID Here *****
$StoreId = echo do_shortcode( '[pcud-user-data f="store-id"]' );

// Create the data access object
$DataCalls = new TestDataCalls();

// Get the form data object
$testDetails = $DataCalls->GetAllTests();

$us_layout = US_Layout::instance();
get_header();
us_load_template( 'templates/titlebar' );
?>
```

Your help us much appreciated! :)

Update:

The code for the shortcode is below.

```
// [pcud-user-data] 
//// print a specific user data
function pcud_data_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    global $pc_users;

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'f' => ''
    ), $atts ) );

    $index = sanitize_title($f);
    $data = pc_user_logged($index);

    return $pc_users->data_to_human($index, $data);
}
add_shortcode('pcud-user-data', 'pcud_data_shortcode');
```

Comment: can you add your shortcode code please

Comment: I've updated the brief to include the shortcode code.

Comment: do you still need help in this or you have solved it?

Comment: Apologies, I still need help.

Comment: did you try passing your passing shortcode directly into the variable, without echo

Comment: That's worked! Thank you Deepti.